# iOS UIWebView is not updating it's size after loading is finished

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I have three `webViews` in 1 `viewController`. All of them are displaying local `html` with inline style sheet (nothing is loaded from any external resources). I want to scale `webViews` height in runtime basing on their content size. The problem is that only the first webView is scaling properly. The 2 remaining are refreshing their size only when I change `view controller` (f.e. go to another part of application) and return.

Here is the code of `viewDidFinishedLoad`

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
  if webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.readyState") == "complete" {
    var height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    debugPrint(height)

    if webView == freeWebview{
        freePriceHeight.constant = height
    }
   if webView == basicPriceWebView{
        bacicWebViewHeight.constant = height
    }
    if webView == premiumTagWebView{
        premiumWebViewHeight.constant = height

    }
    debugPrint(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.innerHTML;"))
    webView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    webView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

All of web views are connected to the same web view delegate. DebugPrints shows that all of them loaded their full content but only the one height is updated

Comment: Are you sure height is the main cause, possibly they are overlapped. As we do not know how views are arrange in hierarchy.

Comment: The view hierarchy is arranged as rootView -> scroll view -> contentView -> [webView, webView, webView]. WebViews are arranged by constraints, first webView is connected to the top of the contentView, the top of the next is connected to the previous bottom. ContentView size for now is fixed and much higher than all of the webViews with full content. After return to the viewController there is a lot of empty space for another elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to load web views only after the previous is fully loaded, so now my code looks

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) { 
    if webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.readyState") == "complete"{
        var height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        if webView == freeWebview{
            freePriceHeight.constant = height
            self.prepareSecondWebView()
        }
        if webView == basicPriceWebView{
            basicWebViewHeight.constant = height
            self.prepareThirdWebView()
        }
        if webView == premiumTagWebView{
            premiumWebViewHeight.constant = height
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.  The key here is the webView loads Asynchrously so you need to make sure all the elements finish loading into it.  Set the controller as the delegate of the webview and in swift 3 the function is this, func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {}

Answer (score 0):

when `webViewDidFinishLoad` instead of

```
webView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
webView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

try

`webView.scalesPageToFit = true`

Comment: doesn't work. WebViews constraints doesn't change, only the content is scaled to fit the device width